# React Native app warning propeT_DO_NOT_PASS_THIS_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have this warning in react native app and cannot find it in react GitHub repository. The only info in commit message is here but I'm not sure is this string is the same:

https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/8bd5b489b4cfc080aca8f93e5487abbeb7fc879d

Why this string 'propeT_DO_NOT_PASS_THIS_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED' is merged in components style?

```
"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native": "0.49.5",
"react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.8.0"
```

[image]

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `0` supplied to `View`.
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184): Bad object: {
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "0": "p",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "1": "r",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "2": "o",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "3": "p",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "4": "e",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "5": "T",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "6": "_",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "7": "D",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "8": "O",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "9": "_",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "10": "N",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "11": "O",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "12": "T",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "13": "_",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "14": "P",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "15": "A",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "16": "S",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "17": "S",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "18": "_",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "19": "T",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "20": "H",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "21": "I",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "22": "S",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "23": "_",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "24": "O",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "25": "R",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "26": "_",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "27": "Y",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "28": "O",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "29": "U",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "30": "_",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "31": "W",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "32": "I",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "33": "L",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "34": "L",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "35": "_",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "36": "B",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "37": "E",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "38": "_",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "39": "F",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "40": "I",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "41": "R",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "42": "E",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "43": "D",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   "style": {
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):     "paddingTop": 10,
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):     "paddingBottom": 10,
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):     "paddingLeft": 14,
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):     "paddingRight": 14,
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):     "flex": 1,
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):     "flexDirection": "row",
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):     "backgroundColor": "#1F1E29"
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184):   }
        W/ReactNativeJS(11184): }
```